# How to add configuration and modules to the android apps : connectivity sample code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, configuration, build.gradle

I am trying to run these connectivity sample apps from android.
[connectivity-samples](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples)

But I am not able to figure out how to add the configuration for the individual app and also there are no modules in the dropdown of modules while trying to add the configuration via existing template.

[image]

any blog or solution will be appreciated, I really want to run all the apps and see how the connectivity works in android.

much much thanks :)

Comment: You can open each directory as an android project. File -> Open -> Go to the main directory of this cloned project -> Choose one of the sub-directory e.g (BeamLargeFiles) -> Open.

Comment: can I not run the individual projects from this parent directory by adding configurations for each sub directory?

Comment: Maybe. But, I am not aware of any other method. Hope you find it.